# Function(x,y) that returns x number of @ separated by y number of spaces

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3.3

How could I go about writing a function that takes two integer parameters, x and y, and prints a string of x number of @'s separated by y number of spaces. For example:

function (4,2) would return a string of

```
"@  @  @  @"
```

and function (2,4) would return a string of

```
"@    @"
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: Hint; you need two loops

Comment: If you're not familiar of python's magic functions, you can just try it with brute-force loops. And then simplify it step by step using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with string multiplication:

```
>>> x,y = 4,2
>>> (' '*y).join('@'*x)
'@  @  @  @'
>>> 
>>> x,y = 2,4
>>> (' '*y).join('@'*x)
'@    @'
```